# Why python asyncio process in a thread seems unstable on Linux?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt5, python-asyncio

I try to run a `python3` asynchronous external command from a Qt Application. Before I was using a multiprocessing thread to do it without freezing the Qt Application. But now, I would like to do it with a `QThread` to be able to pickle and give a `QtWindows` as argument for some other functions (not presented here). I did it and test it with success on my `Windows` OS, but I tried the application on my `Linux` OS, I get the following error :`RuntimeError: Cannot add child handler, the child watcher does not have a loop attached`

From that point I tried to isolate the problem, and I obtain the minimal (as possible as I could) example below that replicates the problem.
Of course, as I mentioned before, if I replace `QThreadPool` by a list of `multiprocessing.thread` this example is working well. I also realized something that astonished me: if I uncomment the line `rc = subp([sys.executable,"./HelloWorld.py"])` in the last part of the example, it works also. I couldn't explain myself why.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

## IMPORTS ##
from functools import partial
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThreadPool, QRunnable, QCoreApplication
import sys
import asyncio.subprocess

# Global variables
Qpool = QtCore.QThreadPool()


def subp(cmd_list):
    """ """

    if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
        new_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(new_loop)
    elif sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        new_loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop() # for subprocess' pipes on Windows
        asyncio.set_event_loop(new_loop)
    else :
        print('[ERROR]     OS not available for encodage... EXIT')
        sys.exit(2)

    rc, stdout, stderr= new_loop.run_until_complete(get_subp(cmd_list) )
    new_loop.close()
    if rc!=0 :
        print('Exit not zero ({}): {}'.format(rc, sys.exc_info()[0]) )#, exc_info=True)
    return rc, stdout, stderr

async def get_subp(cmd_list):
    """ """

    print('subp: '+' '.join(cmd_list) )
    # Create the subprocess, redirect the standard output into a pipe
    create = asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*cmd_list, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE) #
    proc = await create

    # read child's stdout/stderr concurrently (capture and display)
    try:
        stdout, stderr = await asyncio.gather(
            read_stream_and_display(proc.stdout),
            read_stream_and_display(proc.stderr))
    except Exception:
        proc.kill()
        raise
    finally:
        rc = await proc.wait()
        print(" [Exit {}] ".format(rc)+' '.join(cmd_list))
    return rc, stdout, stderr

async def read_stream_and_display(stream):
    """ """
    async for line in stream:
        print(line, flush=True)

class Qrun_from_job(QtCore.QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, job, arg):
        super(Qrun_from_job, self).__init__()
        self.job=job
        self.arg=arg

    def run(self):
        code = partial(self.job)
        code()

def ThdSomething(job,arg):
    testRunnable = Qrun_from_job(job,arg)
    Qpool.start(testRunnable)

def testThatThing():
    rc = subp([sys.executable,"./HelloWorld.py"])


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QCoreApplication([])
    # rc = subp([sys.executable,"./HelloWorld.py"])
    ThdSomething(testThatThing,'tests')
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

with the HelloWorld.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
if __name__=='__main__':
   print('HelloWorld')
   sys.exit(0)
```

Therefore I have two questions: How to make this example working properly with `QThread` ? And why a previous call of an asynchronous task (with a call of `subp` function) change the stability of the example on Linux ?

### EDIT

Following advices of @user4815162342, I tried with a `run_coroutine_threadsafe` with the code below. But it is not working and returns the same error ie `RuntimeError: Cannot add child handler, the child watcher does not have a loop attached`. I also tried to change the `threading` command by its equivalent in the module `mutliprocessing` ; and with the last one, the command `subp` is never launched.

The code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

## IMPORTS ##
import sys
import asyncio.subprocess
import threading
import multiprocessing

# at top-level
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

def spin_loop():
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()

def subp(cmd_list):
    # submit the task to asyncio
    fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(get_subp(cmd_list), loop)
    # wait for the task to finish
    rc, stdout, stderr = fut.result()
    return rc, stdout, stderr

async def get_subp(cmd_list):
    """ """
    print('subp: '+' '.join(cmd_list) )
    # Create the subprocess, redirect the standard output into a pipe
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*cmd_list, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE) #

    # read child's stdout/stderr concurrently (capture and display)
    try:
        stdout, stderr = await asyncio.gather(
            read_stream_and_display(proc.stdout),
            read_stream_and_display(proc.stderr))
    except Exception:
        proc.kill()
        raise
    finally:
        rc = await proc.wait()
        print(" [Exit {}] ".format(rc)+' '.join(cmd_list))
    return rc, stdout, stderr

async def read_stream_and_display(stream):
    """ """
    async for line in stream:
        print(line, flush=True)

if __name__=='__main__':
    threading.Thread(target=spin_loop, daemon=True).start()
    # multiprocessing.Process(target=spin_loop, daemon=True).start()
    print('thread passed')
    rc = subp([sys.executable,"./HelloWorld.py"])
    print('end')
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: As a general design principle, it's unnecessary and wasteful to create new event loops only to run a single subroutine. Instead, create an event loop and run it in a separate thread. The single event loop is perfectly capable of servicing multiple requests at once - in fact, that's what it's good at. Use `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` to submit a coroutine to the event loop, and use the `result()` method to wait until the coroutine is complete. (You can also use `add_done_callback` to be notified when the result is available, in which case you might need the thread to begin with.)

Comment: @user4815162342 Do you think that might solve the problem ?

Comment: @user4815162342 otherwise, I do agree with your principle even if I get some trouble to apply it here.

Comment: Yes, I think that will solve the issue. I can't prove it because I can't easily run your code, and I didn't want to post it as an answer because it doesn't directly address your question.

Comment: I edit my question with a try with `run_coroutine_threadsafe`.

Comment: I've now posted my comment as an answer that includes actual code. Hopefully that will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general design principle, it's unnecessary and wasteful to create new event loops only to run a single subroutine. Instead, create an event loop, run it in a separate thread, and use it for all your asyncio needs by submitting tasks to it using [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe).

For example:

```
# at top-level
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
def spin_loop():
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()

asyncio.get_child_watcher().attach_loop(loop)
threading.Thread(target=spin_loop, daemon=True).start()
# ... the rest of your code ...
```

With this in place, you can easily execute any asyncio code from any thread whatsoever using the following:

```
def subp(cmd_list):
    # submit the task to asyncio
    fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(get_subp(cmd_list), loop)
    # wait for the task to finish
    rc, stdout, stderr = fut.result()
    return rc, stdout, stderr
```

Note that you can use `add_done_callback` to be notified when the future returned by `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` finishes, so you might not need a thread in the first place.

Note that all interaction with the event loop should go either through the afore-mentioned `run_coroutine_threadsafe` (when submitting coroutines) or through [`loop.call_soon_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon_threadsafe) when you need the event loop to call an ordinary function. For example, to stop the event loop, you would invoke `loop.call_soon_threadsafe(loop.stop)`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Unfortunately it did not solve the problem (except if I misunderstood), but maybe it helps to isolate it more precisely. I re-edit my question to include the cleanest understanding of your solution I could make. Maybe you will have a better idea of the problem.

Comment: @R.N This time you understood it perfectly, and kudos on the minimal example - removing the Qt dependency made it possible for me to run it. I got it to work by adding `asyncio.get_child_watcher().attach_loop(loop)` before starting the thread. This removes the error in the minimal example. I've amended the answer accordingly.

Comment: I tested your amendment, which works very well this time. I will validate your answer soon. I just have a dummy question before: how do you stop properly the forever running loop, from `spin_loop`? Because I tried with `loop.stop()` but after-what  if I check with `print(loop.is_running())` the answer is True ; and if I try with `loop.close()` I get an error since I can't close a running loop.

Comment: @R.N All interaction with the loop from outside its own thread need to go through `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` (for coroutines) or [`loop.call_soon_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon_threadsafe) (for ordinary functions). You'd stop the loop with `loop.call_soon_threadsafe(loop.stop)`. Those functions will lock the appropriate mutex, and also alert the event loop that it something new has happened that it needs to pay attention to.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that what you are doing is simply unsupported - according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html):

> To handle signals and to execute subprocesses, the event loop must be run in the main thread.

As you are trying to execute a subprocess, I do not think running a new event loop in another thread works.

Thing is, Qt already has an event loop, and what you really need is to convince `asyncio` to use it. That means that you need an event loop implementation that provides the "event loop interface for asyncio" implemented on top of "Qt's event loop".

I believe that [asyncqt](https://github.com/gmarull/asyncqt) provides such an implementation. You may want to try to use `QEventLoop(app)` in place of `asyncio.new_event_loop()`.

Comment: In fact, using the solution brought by @user4815162342, I succeed to execute a subprocess in loop run in a new `QThread` ie not in the main loop. Otherwise, thanks from the reference asyncqt that I did not know.

Comment: You are correct, though I hope that the docs are being too strict here and that the restriction will be lifted at some point. While it's true that _setting up_ the child watcher involves signal-handling code that must be run from the main thread, the delivery of `SIGCHLD` does not depend on the event loop running in the main thread. The signal will be delivered to the main thread, but the handler will just write a byte to a pipe, which will be picked up by the event loop regardless of where it's running. This is why the code from the answer works.

Comment: I have the same problem where I could not run my QThread in linux but it works on Windows. Could you post a snippet of your code that executes a subprocess in a QThread?